# Localized Raw files

Tags: android, resources

I have several raw files in my application.

Now, they are language specific, and I want, if user's language is different than the one provided in the raw folder (for instance if i have raw-he, and the device language is not hebrew), i want it to fallback on nothing, meaning the action would fail.

Do I have to :
 check if the file exists in the raw folder based on user's device locale?

Or

I can do something, besides putting empty sound files in the raw folder, to make it fall back on nothing ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put the file name into the localizable strings. So for example in res/values-he/strings.xml you'll have:

```
<string name="raw_file_name">he-raw-file</string>
```

and in res/values/strings.xml you can leave the string empty:

```
<string name="raw_file_name"></string>
```

Then just check against the string you load from resources to not being empty.